# make C++ Library with qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll

i build a C++ library with qt creator. 
qt builds for me in debug folder 3 files:

> ```
> '1. libSerialize.a' and '2. Serialize.dll' and 'serialize.o' .
> ```

now i want to add this library to another qt project. 
how can i do that?.
how can i include that library? .
where should i copy those? .
which one is necessary? .
this is my `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = get_send_array
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp \
    student.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h \
    student.h
```

so thanks, please help me.

Comment: Hi. I see you're using QtCreator. Try right-clicking on the project parent folder, in the project tree, and select *Add Library*. If it recognizes your new library, QtCreator will modify the *.pro* file accordingly and you won't have to mess with it.

Comment: ok, but when i want to add he wants a .lib file but i don't have that, how can i build it?

Comment: Well, @maverik answer seems the right one. But about the `.a`... In our Windows project we use a bunch of `.a` files, like this: `LIBS += "C:/MY_PROJECT/libs/my_lib.a"`. It works. You just need to update it with the path to your `.a`. Also, I would like to know if this is the right approach...

Comment: i mean   qt creator wants **.lib** file.

Comment: @ErfanTavakoli If you are using GNU suite you can try `ar rcs libSerialize.a libSerialize.lib`. But it should work with `a` archives. Basically `a` files are collections of so called object `*.o` files. So your `serialize.o` is packed into `libSerialize.a` archive.

Comment: @ErfanTavakoli: If you don't have or can't make a `.lib` file, try what I said, adding to the `LIB` var the path to your `.a` object, with extension included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
win32:LIBS += /path/to/the/lib/Serialize.dll
unix:LIBS += -L/path/to/the/lib/ -lSerialize
```

`Serialize.dll` is a windows dynamic load library, and `libSerialize.a` is an `ar` archive (you may reffer to it as a static library) and usually used in *nix systems.

Comment: To be strict `lib` is a format used by Microsoft, while `a` is widely used by GNU compilers (also on Windows).

Comment: ok, i add those to  .pro  but how can i use from that library? should i write include <serialize.lib> ?

Comment: You should include library's header file. Something like `#include "serialize.h"`

Comment: @ErfanTavakoli No, in your source code you should include file containing declarations of your API. I suspect that while creating your library you have written some header files like `serialize.h` and those should be included in your project. Your project will also be compiled into object `o` files and then the linker will merge the generated stuff for the library (`a`, `dll', `lib` etc) with project files to generate final executable. Sorry for being laconic, but this tiny box isn't the best place to describe this fairly large topic. Read some tutorial about using and creating libs.

Comment: `-L/path/to/the/lib/ -lSerialize` is working on windows too (at least with mingw)...
This : `/path/to/the/lib/Serialize.dll` is wrong and to force to use static lib use : `/path/to/the/lib/Serialize.a`

Comment: @benjarobin Not for all compilers.